# Qual a diferença do find e filter do jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lembrei que existe uma função no jQuery chamada de `filter`. Eu já conheço o `find`, mas quero saber se existe alguma diferença entre eles ou se são a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 13):

**Diferença**

- `find` encontra os elementos que atendem à expressão solicitada que sejam **descendentes** do seletor.
- `filter`, por outro lado, filtra e devolve todos os elementos que coincidam com o seletor **e também** a expressão filtrada.

**Exemplo**

No exemplo abaixo, um `$('div').filter('.teste')` vai encontrar o **Bloco 1** e o **Sub 3**, pois ambos são `div`s que atendem o filtro pela classe `teste`.

Por sua vez, um `$('div').find('.teste')` vai encontrar apenas o **Sub 3**, pois apenas dentro do seletor `div` do "Bloco 2" há um descendente cuja classe é `teste`.

```html
<div class="teste">
   Bloco 1
   <div class="limao">Sub 1</div>
   <div class="trevo">Sub 2</div>
</div>

<div class="pardo">
   Bloco 2
   <div class="teste">Sub 3</div>
   <div class="peixe">Sub 4</div>
</div>
```

> Clique aqui para ver um [exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3EDX8/).

Comment: Você pode ter dois ou mais elementos com o mesmo `id`?! Sempre que eu fiz isso [acidentalmente] o browser simplesmente ignorou um deles, levando a todo tipo de bug. Ou tem algo que não estou enxergando?

Comment: @mgibsonbr O correto não é usar dois IDs nunca, na verdade. Por outro lado, para efeitos de DOM e JQuery não  dá problema (inclusive se você experimentar inventar tags e atributos totalmente fora do padrão ele funciona bem). Talvez pra fins de "didática de SO" seja o caso de eu trocar por class, aproveitando que vou fazer um exemplo melhor no jsfiddle.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Fiz a troca, concordo que é melhor não dar margem pra confusão mesmo.

Answer (score 6):

A função do [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) é buscar elementos **descendentes** daquele(s) selecionado(s), enquanto a função do [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) é criar um **subconjunto** dos próprios elementos. Exemplo:

```
<div id="div1" class="a top">
  <div id="sub1" class="b"></div>
  <div id="sub2" class="b"></div>
  <div>
      <div id="sub3" class="b"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="b top"></div>
<div class="b top"></div>
<div id="div2" class="a top"></div>
<div id="div3" class="a top"></div>
```

O seguinte código pega `sub1`, `sub2` e `sub3`:

```
$("#div1").find(".b");
```

Já o seguinte código pega `div1`, `div2` e `div3`:

```
$(".top").filter(".a");
```

Uma maneira alternativa de se invocar o `filter` é passando uma função como argumento, em vez de um seletor. Isso permite que você execute alguma lógica mais complicada ao escolher se determinado elemento vai entrar ou não no subconjunto requisitado:

```
$(".top").filter(function(indice) {
    var elemento = this, $elemento = $(this);
    return ...; // Se true, o elemento entra no resultado.
});
```

Comment: mas uma dúvida, então **filter** é igual a **is**?

Comment: @IagoBruno Não exatamente, o [`.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) verifica se **algum** elemento satisfaz a condição, retornando `true` (e potencialmente parando o trabalho por aí, sem consultar o resto). Se **nenhum** deles satisfaz, retorna `false`. O `filter` passa por todos os elementos, e retorna uma nova lista (i.e. um novo objeto jQuery) contendo somente os elementos que satisfizeram a condição (ou a lista vazia se nenhum satisfaz).

Comment: ah ta \o/ e mais uma coisa rsrs, para que serve o addBack?

Comment: @IagoBruno Aí já foge um pouco do meu conhecimento. `addBack`, `andSelf`, `end` etc mexem numa coisa que o jQuery chama de "stack" (pilha [de conjuntos]), e que muda cada vez que você chama um método no objeto jQuery. O assunto é complexo, vale a pena uma pergunta separada para isso (aliás, acho que eu próprio vou fazer)

Comment: haha ok e que eu vi uma vez e não olhei para que serve, **obrigado** ^_^

Answer (score 4):

Resumo fácil de entender usando exemplos:

`$('div a')` retorna o mesmo que `$('div').find('a')`

`$('body .teste strong')` retorna o mesmo que `$('body').find('.teste').find('strong')`

`$('.minhaClasse span')` retorna o mesmo que `$('.minhaClasse').find('span')`

`$('.foo .bar')` retorna o mesmo que `$('.foo').find('.bar')`

---

`$('div:gt(0)')` retorna o mesmo que `$('div').filter(':gt(0)')`

`$('div:hidden')` retorna o mesmo que `$('div').filter(':hidden')`

`$('div[data-teste]')` retorna o mesmo que `$('div').filter('[data-teste]')`

`$('a[title]')` retorna o mesmo que `$('a').filter('[title]')`

`$('option:selected')` retorna o mesmo que `$('option').filter(':selected')`

`$('.foo.bar')` retorna o mesmo que `$('.foo').filter('.bar')`

---

Percebeu a diferença?

O método `filter` reduz o seletor atual de acordo com um filtro, como um atributo (href, name, value, src, data-*, for, maxlength, action, etc.), uma pseudoclasse (:hidden, :visible, :hover, :active, :checked, :selected, :empty, etc), entre outros.

O método `find` serve para encontrar elementos descendentes do(s) selector(es) especificado(s).

Answer (score 3):

O `find` procura nós dentro de um elemento, enquanto o `filter` filtra os nós selecionados com outro seletor.

`$('div').find('p')` procura parágrafos dentro de div's, enquanto `$('div').filter('.a')` seleciona apenas div's com a classe CSS "a".